# Custom Header in Mono for Android App

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm working on my first app using Mono for Android. I feel like I'm trying to do something basic but I'm not having any luck. Essentially, I want to have a custom "banner" at the top of my app. The banner is simply a black rectangle with two words: "Hello" and "World". Hello is in red, and World is in Blue.

I'm not getting anywhere with this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is: "Does anyone know how to do this?"? The answer is yes, there is someone out there who knows how to do this. Rephrase your question and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic layout example to get you started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="World"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#0000FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The rest of your activity layout goes here.  -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This places a banner at the top of the screen. However, I want to replace the area set in the initial Activity. Currently, my Activity has an attribute the looks like the following:     [Activity(Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]. MyApp is shown as text with a gray background. How do I replace that portion with a custom banner?

Comment: Figured it out right after I asked. I used your code with this.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);